# Why does this exceed the 65,535 byte limit in Java constructors and static Initializers?

Tags: java, jls

**Disclaimer: I realize I can generate this at runtime in Java, this was needed for a very special case while performance testing some code. I've found a different approach, so now this is just more of a curiosity than anything practical.**

I've tried the following as a static field, as an instance field, and initialized directly within the constructor. Every time eclipse is informing me that either "The code of constructor TestData() is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit" or "The code for the static initializer is exceeding the 65535 bytes limit".

There are 10,000 integers. If each int is 4 bytes (32bits), then would that not be 40,000 bytes? Is there really more that 25,0000 bytes of overhead in addition to the data just merely constructing the array?

The data is generated with this small bit of python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import random;
print "public final int[] RANDOM_INTEGERS = new int[] {";
for i in range(1,10000):
    print str(int(random.uniform(0,0x7fffffff))) + ",";
print "};";
```

Here's a small sample:

```
public final int[] RANDOM_INTEGERS = new int[] {
    963056418, 460816633, 1426956928, 1836901854, 334443802, 721185237, 488810483,
    1734703787, 1858674527, 112552804, 1467830977, 1533524842, 1140643114, 1452361499,
    716999590, 652029167, 1448309605, 1111915190, 1032718128, 1194366355, 112834025,
    419247979, 944166634, 205228045, 1920916263, 1102820742, 1504720637, 757008315,
    67604636, 1686232265, 597601176, 1090143513, 205960256, 1611222388, 1997832237,
    1429883982, 1693885243, 1987916675, 159802771, 1092244159, 1224816153, 1675311441,
    1873372604, 1787757434, 1347615328, 1868311855, 1401477617, 508641277, 1352501377,
    1442984254, 1468392589, 1059757519, 1898445041, 1368044543, 513517087, 99625132,
    1291863875, 654253390, 169170318, 2117466849, 1711924068, 564675178, 208741732,
    1095240821, 1993892374, 87422510, 1651783681, 1536657700, 1039420228, 674134447,
    1083424612, 2137469237, 1294104182, 964677542, 1506442822, 1521039575, 64073383,
    929517073, 206993014, 466196357, 1139633501, 1692533218, 1934476545, 2066226407,
    550646675, 624977767, 1494512072, 1230119126, 1956454185, 1321128794, 2099617717,
    //.... to 10,0000 instances
```

Comment: In reading up on this I find that this limit applies to all methods (including constructors) as well as static initializers. Interesting!

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.java.machine/browse_thread/thread/b0cf268515f1ef55

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is the bytecode for initializing an array with {1000001, 1000002, 1000003}:

```
 5  iconst_3
 6  newarray int [10]
 8  dup
 9  iconst_0
10  ldc <Integer 1000001> [12]
12  iastore
13  dup
14  iconst_1
15  ldc <Integer 1000002> [13]
17  iastore
18  dup
19  iconst_2
20  ldc <Integer 1000003> [14]
22  iastore
23  putfield net.jstuber.test.TestArrayInitializingConstructor.data : int[] [15]
```

So for this small array each element requires 5 bytes of Java bytecode. For your bigger array both the array index and the index into the constant pool will use 3 bytes for most elements, which leads to 8 bytes per array element. So for 10000 elements you'd have to expect about 80kB of byte code.

The code for initializing big arrays with 16 bit indices looks like this:

```
2016  dup
2017  sipush 298
2020  ldc_w <Integer 100298> [310]
2023  iastore
2024  dup
2025  sipush 299
2028  ldc_w <Integer 100299> [311]
```

Comment: Are string literals handled specially?  Are they the only thing that is?  Would it make sense to initialize arrays by packing the data into string literals [perhaps saying, for `int` values, that numbers +/-16383 store as one character, +/- 268435455 or certain other select values store as two, and anything else as three]?

Comment: @supercat Yes, that could work. Each string uses up two constant pool indexes, one for the string (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.3) and one for the actual UTF-8 data (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.7). As far as I can see there is no other constant type of somewhat arbitrary size (see 4.4 The Constant Pool http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4).  Though I'd rather use a resource than such a hack.

Answer (score 7):

Array literals are translated into the byte code that fills the array with the values, so you need a few more bytes for each number.

Why not move that data out into a resource that you load at class-loading time in a static initializer block? This can easily be done by using `MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream()`. It seems that this it where it belongs, anyway.

Or better yet, create the random values in the static initializer block using the Java tools available. And if you need repeatable "random" numbers, then just seed the `Random` instance with a fixed, but randomly choosen number each time.

Comment: The environment being tested does not allow file I/O access.

Comment: But you're loading classes, so you probably can do MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream() and load it from the jar you package your application in. That should *always* be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the values of the integers, the constructor and the initializer needs to contain the JVM instructions for loading the integers into the array.

Comment: So I guess this is what I was expecting, just surprising an array literal init code is > 25,000 bytes (I'm sure there's some small overhead in the setup of the class/method/etc).

Comment: You can use javap to see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A much simpler and more practical approach is to store the numbers in a file, either in a binary format or as text.

I don't know what java initialises arrays this way, but it does not initialise large arrays efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I think that code size in characters is more than 65535. Not the memory taken by 10000 integers.

Comment: 11 characters times 10,000 entries is 110,000 bytes, more or less. Absolutely over the limit

Comment: Why was this answer downvoted? It's correct, in a minimalist kind of way.

Answer (score -5):

I think it's possible that this is the amount of memory required to represent those ints alphanumerically. I think this limit might apply for the code itself, so, each int, for instance: 1494512072 actually takes 10 bytes ( one per digit ) instead of only 4 bytes used for the int32.

Comment: I'm fairly sure the "code" being referenced in the error message is referring to the generated bytecode.